# Программное добавление компоненты в UIView, созданный из Nib файла

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Я хочу привязать в interface builder'e компоненту к некоторому UIViewController. А сам этот UIViewController работает таким образом, что постоянно добавляет и удаляет внутри себя компоненты (subview). Возможно ли такое?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, возможно.

Делается это очень просто:

```
//внутри UIViewController'a, где требуется добавление
UIView * subView = ...//ваш view, который Вы хотите добавить
subView.frame = ...   //устанавливаем положение
[self.view addSubview:subView]; //добавляем на форму
```

Чтобы убрать воспользуйтесь

```
[subView removeFromSuperview];
```